# Split string by colon but ignore URL's

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string by colons, but ignore colons within urls presented in that string. For example:

```
var str = 'www.website.com:http://website.com/';
```

The result should be:

```
["www.website.com", "http://website.com/"]
```

It may be a lot of addresses in the row.

I have tried a javascript `split()` with some regex like `(:)(?:[^\/][^\/])` but that not helping much.

Comment: Did you try anything, have any code to share? Or do you just expect someone to write the solution for you?

Comment: I'm not sure this question should be so much downvoted. A clean code for that isn't trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use negative lookahead you can filter out any protocols (colons followed by double slash) and ports (colons followed by a digit:

```
var str = 'www.website.com:http://website.com/:test.com:5000:test.co.uk';  
var split = str.split(/:(?!\/\/|\d)/);
```

Comment: What about ports, e.g., `domain.com:5000`?

Comment: ..which then fails on domainnames starting with digits: 37signals.com (using same format as the current 'test.com:5000' testcase) (answer v2).

Comment: ...which is why OP should never use an actual string character (and a very frequent one) as a delimiter...